# ChromeCast (gen3) setup phase - viable to hijacks?

Tags: security, chromecast

I just realized that when you setup a ChromeCast for the first time, it doesn't even ask what number is shown on the TV screen. It just asks whether or not you actually see the same number.

Furthermore, at this point it does not yet require your wifi password or anything. It only need to be within bluetooth's range and some bluetooth antennaes have above average range.

So if one lives in an appartment building, isn't the Chromecast viable to hijacks if someone has a script running that's scanning for Chromecasts on a regular basis and just basically answering "yes, I see the pincode on the TV screen".

In this scenario, even pressing the reset button on the CC wouldn't actually help since you'd be stuck at the same situation.

While marginal, I think this sounds like a huge security issue.

And I'm not talking about Guest Mode here. I'm talking about the actual setup phase where you take control of the CC for the first time.

And no: I'm not talking about probabilities here like "well how likely is this scenario to happen?" - I'm talking about whether or not it's actually still possible and there's no solution against it.

Comment: I agree but wasn't there a part where you enter the code you see on  the TV in the previous chromecast?

Comment: @Y4glory yes, but it didn't require you to input that said code. You could just answer "yes, I see it" just like any other person who actually doesn't see it. That's the problem. There's no verification whatsoever. It reminds me of "are these your keys?" --> "yes".